# Is there anything that forbids an Article 409 industrial control panel within a dwelling unit?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance, nec

Can an "industrial control panel", complying with NEC Article 409 and constructed with UL 508 listed devices, be used to control loads in a dwelling unit/residential occupancy? It would rely on the fault protection of the upstream circuit instead of having breakers inside it (this is allowed for an Article 409 panel) and be located indoors, within a NEMA 1 enclosure with a dead front.

Comment: I think I've seen this done before where the electrical contractor used a transfer switch in junction as a control panel.  Because the generator was feeding the whole house, they used relays and fuses to keep the heavy loads off the backup power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my reading of Article 409 and the scope of UL 508 I don't see anything that actually requires or prohibits a control panel's installation by occupancy.

The word "Industrial" is a misnomer in my opinion since many commercial spaces (and probably more than a few residences) have devices that would fit the definition of an "Industrial Control Panel". (This may be a good place for a suggested change to the Code.)

Here is the definition from Article 409.2:

> **Industrial Control Panel.** An assembly of two or more components consisting of one of the following:
>
> (1) Power circuit components only, such as motor controllers, overload relays, fused disconnect switches, and circuit breakers
>
> (2) Control circuit components only, such as pushbuttons, pilot lights, selector switches, timers, switches, control relays
>
> (3) A combination of power and control circuit components
>
> These components, with associated wiring and terminals, are mounted on or contained within an enclosure or mounted on a subpanel. The industrial control panel does not include the controlled equipment.

So, if I were to install a box with a timer and a relay to control a recirculation pump for my water heater I have just installed an "Industrial Control Panel".

The informational note in Article 409 that refers to UL 508 is not enforceable code so the panel does not have to be listed by UL or anyone else. The Code just suggests this as a source of information when considering the installation of such a panel. The industry practice of field building these panels with separate components is decades old and will continue for years to come.

If someone wants to take one of these prebuilt panels home and re-purpose it for some other task then there is nothing in the Code that prohibits that.